# Tables pagination php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

i got pagination code from somewhere on this site and I am using it now.
Only problem is that I am unable to paginate content directly from my html/php file, the only thing I can paginate is the tables I create in the database.

I thought it would be simple, create table in html/php file and that's it :/ wasn't so simple... I was hoping I'd just put the code on my site, change the names(id, firstname, country) to class/id names on my divs and it would paginate the whole content on that page, isn't that how it's supposed to work?

The code I'm using:

```
<?php
// Custom PHP MySQL Pagination Tutorial and Script
// You have to put your mysql connection data and alter the SQL queries(both queries)

mysql_connect("localhost","myUserName","myPassWord") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("myDataBase") or die (mysql_error());
//////////////  QUERY THE MEMBER DATA INITIALLY LIKE YOU NORMALLY WOULD
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, country FROM myTable ORDER BY id ASC");
//////////////////////////////////// Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql); // Get total of Num rows from the database query
if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { // Get pn from URL vars if it is present
    $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(new)
    //$pn = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(deprecated)
} else { // If the pn URL variable is not present force it to be value of page number 1
    $pn = 1;
}
//This is where we set how many database items to show on each page
$itemsPerPage = 10;
// Get the value of the last page in the pagination result set
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
// Be sure URL variable $pn(page number) is no lower than page 1 and no higher than $lastpage
if ($pn < 1) { // If it is less than 1
    $pn = 1; // force if to be 1
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { // if it is greater than $lastpage
    $pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value
}
// This creates the numbers to click in between the next and back buttons
// This section is explained well in the video that accompanies this script
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
// This line sets the "LIMIT" range... the 2 values we place to choose a range of rows from database in our query
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;
// Now we are going to run the same query as above but this time add $limit onto the end of the SQL syntax
// $sql2 is what we will use to fuel our while loop statement below
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, country FROM myTable ORDER BY id ASC $limit");
//////////////////////////////// END Pagination Logic ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////// Pagination Display Setup /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$paginationDisplay = ""; // Initialize the pagination output variable
// This code runs only if the last page variable is ot equal to 1, if it is only 1 page we require no paginated links to display
if ($lastPage != "1"){
    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
    // If we are not on page 1 we can place the Back button
    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
    }
    // Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the Back and Next links
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    // If we are not on the very last page we can place the Next button
    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////// END Pagination Display Setup ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Build the Output Section Here
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

    $id = $row["id"];
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $country = $row["country"];

    $outputList .= '<h1>' . $firstname . '</h1><h2>' . $country . ' </h2><hr />';

} // close while loop
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Pagination</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;">
     <h2>Total Items: <?php echo $nr; ?></h2>
   </div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:red; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
      <div style="margin-left:64px; margin-right:64px;"><?php print "$outputList"; ?></div>
      <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest creating your own script rather than trying hack someone else's spaghetti.  To start with, are you sure the query is returning what you expect?  And if so, is it in a format (multi dim array) that is going to paginate properly?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You may very well get a deprecation notice, since you're using `mysql_` functions. If that is the case, then you'll need to use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: I would like to but I'm a beginner at php and everything else and couldn't do that :(. 
Well it's returning whatever I put inside of my table in my database, so that much is clear but I don't know more than that. I don't know what to expect from pagination since I don't know how it's supposed to work but I assume it's supposed to paginate data on your html/php without the need of creating a table on database each time you put something new on your site.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll do that now and see what happens